# Why there is no constant expression string constructor in the STL?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stl, constexpr

It seems that in C++ the only way to have string literals fully in the **static memory** is to declare them as:

```
class A
{
    static const char const * = "Hello World";
};
```

I noticed that **std::string** has no **constant expression constructor**. 
I know the **std::string** implementation is based on **dynamic allocation**, but why there is not another string class, compliant with **std::string**, which can do the job?

Comment: Is [`std::experimental::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view) what you're looking for?

Comment: Next time please do compile your code before posting....

Comment: @TartanLlama yes it is indeed, thanks. The name string_view was not helping googling them out. Do you know if this experimental class is scheduled for c++17?

Comment: `static constexpr char bob[]="Hello World";` is distinct from your version, yet also in static memory.  Unlike your version, we did not discard the buffer size information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for [`std::experimental::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view), which allows the standard string types and C-strings to be accessed in a unified, efficient manner.

It is part of the [Library Fundamentals TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#string.view), which has been published and may make it in to C++17.

Comment: Unfortunately, while `constexpr string_view::string_view(const char*)` is `constexpr`, it calls `char_traits<char>::length`, which is not `constexpr`, so it still won't work.  For instance, `static const constexpr std::experimental::string_view sv("Hello, world");` won't compile.  While I disagree, other committee members have told me this works as designed.

Comment: @Nevin How can that work? If i remember well, a constexpr subroutine can call only other constexpr subroutines...

Comment: @nyarlathotep108  I've been told the constexpr on the basic_string_view constructor<charT, traits> is, at this point, only for those people who use their own traits instead of std::char_traits and not for the users of string_view, wstring_view, u16string_view and u32string_view, in much the same way that pair has constexpr constructors.  For the record, I do not agree with this position.  Anyway, [LWG 2232](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2232) goes into some detail on why this isn't easy to solve for char_traits<char>.